# Prevent checkbox inside a div from firing the divs function

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a list with divs that on click expand the div below them. This is working perfectly fine.
Now I want to add a checkbox to the clickable div but everytime the checkbox is clicked it fires the function of the div where it's placed, this makes the div expand at the same time the box is checked and viceversa.
I want to check and uncheck the box without triggering the div behind it.
[Expandable divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us6aV.png)

Comment: Try to add e.preventDefault() in the handler of the click in the checkbox ?

Comment: Please post the code and not images. We can not help you in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to add `event.stopPropagation()` in the click callback of the checkbox. That will prevent the click event from bubbling up to the `div`.

An example:

```
$('input:checkbox').on("click", function(event) {
    // Do something here
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Works and it's terribly simple, im still learning sorry to bother ty

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hacky way to do it, but it might work:

```
<script>

    var prevent_div_click = false;

    $(function(){

        $('#div-id').on('mouseenter', '#checkbox-id', function(){
            prevent_div_click = true;
        });

        $('#div-id').on('mouseleave', '#checkbox-id', function(){
            prevent_div_click = false;
        });

        $('#div-id').click(function(){
            if(!prevent_div_click){
                // do your stuff
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```